# Word prediction using quadgams in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, n-gram

I am currently using Quadgrams in python to predict the next word of a sentence. For this I am using nested dictionary to store the probabilities. [Here is the link for the code](https://github.com/MeghanaBandaru/2017-summer-internship/blob/master/quad_prob_model_test.py)

But this implementation takes O(n) in the worst case. So is there any other way to implement this using other data structures that take O(logn) or lesser for lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Ternary search trees are efficient data structures to implement autocomplete. You can store probabilities in the nodes (100% if there's no branching, and X% if branching).

Lookup would be in O(log n).

Comment: Thank you Eric. In my problem I have approx 200K quadgrams and 50K vocabulary . Can you please tell me how can I implement this if a node has only 3 branches as in Ternary search trees.

Comment: It's the same principle as a binary search tree, except you search character by character, the middle branch is if there's a match, and left branch is if the character you're searching for comes before the character contained in the middle branch, and the converse for the right branch. Consult these slides for more details (begins slide 22): http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/52Tries.pdf